# How old is Ross Geller?

Tags: character, friends

In season 3 of Friends, Ross Geller says that he is 29 years old.

In season 4 of Friends, Ross again states that he is 29 years old.

In season 5, Ross talks about getting divorced twice before turning 30.

Is Ross stuck in some sort of time dilation where he doesn't age, perhaps being in denial about his age or is there some other explanation for how he doesn't seem to get older over a three year period in the show?

Comment: In season 4, Gunther asks Rachel when her birthday is, and Ross starts to say that his birthday is in December but does not mention the day.

Comment: In season one episode four, Ross states his birthday was "seven months ago" in response to a hockey game taking place on on "the 20th, October 20th?".

Comment: On episode 5 of the fourth season, Ross tells Gunter that his birthday is sometime in December.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[**FRIENDS Wiki**](http://friends.wikia.com/wiki/Ross_Geller#Age_and_birthday) points out that:

> **Ross's age is treated inconsistently by the show's writers**, the best evidence is that he was born on October 18, 1967.

There are several episodes in which Ross's birthday/age is either mentioned or hinted at, but they often contradict each other (click the link for details).

Comment: There is an episode in Season 4 where Gunther asks Rachel when is her birthday also saying that he marking people's birthday in his calendar, Ross then says "Mine is December.." and then Gunther says "Yeah whatever". Meaning, there is also inconsistency in the actual date.

I know the October 18th is from an episode from season 9 where Joy fractures Ross' thumb

Comment: My Lebanese best friend's birth certificate says a different day (and month) than she celebrates, and her grandmother and uncles disagree on when her mum's true birthday is. This is quite common in some parts of the world! See for example Khaleda Zia "Zia claims 15 August as her birthday... Her matriculation examination certificate lists a birth date of 9 August 1945. Her marriage certificate lists 5 September 1945. Zia's passport indicates a birth date of 19 August 1945." -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khaleda_Zia#Birthday_controversy

Comment: @BraveChris It is not good form to edit something in a block quote as you are misattributing words to the original author.